# Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom not working

Tags: c#, reflection, remoting

I have an Assembly `Library1.dll` which contains some Interfaces, which were serialized as a byte array into the database. For some reasons we have to change the Interface properties and defintion. so now i am writing a migration utility. So i have 2 versions of `Library1.dll` , In my utility i have created a folder where i store the new version of `Library1.dll` . This utility in turn also references `Library1.dll` hence in bin folder contains `Library1.dll` but this dll is compiled on older version. My new version of `Library1.dll` is stored in a private path which i am passing to `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom` function to instantiate and hence `GetTypes` on the assembly loaded which further would enable me to do conversion of data.

But I always get `ReflectionTypeLoadException` when trying to load `Library1.dll` from private path.

Please help guys!!!. any help would be appreciated. I am really stuck.

Thanks,
AG

Comment: What are the LoaderExceptions on the ReflectionOnlyLoadFromException?
http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/08/11/57236.aspx

Comment: What is it that you are trying to "migrate"? Data? or the dll itself?

Answer (score 20):

If your Library is referencing another dll, *GetTypes* will fail when it hits a type that uses an external type. Unlike normal assembly loading, ReflectionOnly Assembly loading will not resolve dependencies. You can either subscribe to *AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve* and load the dependencies as required, or you could pre-load them.

This is the code I use for this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyPath);
foreach (var assemblyName in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()) {
  try {
    Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(assemblyName.FullName);
  } catch {
    Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath), assemblyName.Name + ".dll"));
  }
}
```

This will try to load all dependencies of the reflection-only loaded assembly first by fullname, then by path (assuming that the dependency is in the same directory as the loaded assembly).

Comment: Arne: You helped us out a lot here.  We were banging our heads against the wall pretty hard.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/08/24/219691.aspx for sample code that uses ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve.