# Missing types using reflection on DLL

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes, .net-assembly

I'm writing a program that uses reflection to look at a DLL, and obtain the table names/enums within.

After obtaining the assembly using the method "ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom" to avoid having to load all dependencies, I use the following code to grab the types:

```
try
{
    types = assembly.GetTypes();
}
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
{
    types = ex.Types.Where(p => p != null).ToArray();
}
```

This returns *most* of the types, but the ones I really need are not listed here.

The commonality between the missing types are that they all use Custom Attributes in the class (C#) as part of the data access layer. The table is defined above the class name in an attribute, and each property has an attribute above it to define it as a column in the DB.

Could custom attributes be causing an issue in relation to reflection, in that types aren't returned when they are present?

Comment: Is it hitting your catch block?  It would not surprise me if this failed on a custom attribute if that attribute is defined elsewhere.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321293/assembly-reflectiononlyloadfrom-not-working

Comment: Yep, I forgot to mention "GetTypes()" never gets hit, it always goes in to the catch and gets the types from the ReflectionTypeLoadException.

Comment: I was previously using "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve" but using the code given in the answer to that SO link has done the trick. Thanks!